# Lag with video display and long delay in saving video from web camera using Gstreamer

Tags: python, video, gstreamer

My flow is as follows Pipeline 1: to read camera frames -> Queue -> other processing on frames in queue -> Pipeline 2:- to save video.

pipeline 1: camera reader

```
        videosrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("mfvideosrc", "videosrc")
        videosrc.set_property("device-index", device_number)
        caps = Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw, framerate=30/1")
        capsfilter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", None)
        capsfilter.set_property("caps", caps)
        self.appsink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("appsink", "appsink")

        # Link elements
        videosrc.link(capsfilter)
        capsfilter.link(self.appsink)
```

pipeline- 2: video writer

```
        self.appsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("appsrc", "source")
        gstqueue = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "queue")
        videoconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "videoconvert")
        mfh264enc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("mfh264enc", "mfh264enc")
        h264parse = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse", "h264parse")
        qtmux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("qtmux", "qtmux")

        # Link elements
        self.appsrc.link(gstqueue)
        gstqueue.link(videoconvert)
        videoconvert.link(mfh264enc)
        mfh264enc.link(h264parse)
        h264parse.link(qtmux)
        qtmux.link(filesink)
```

Some processing are done to frames in the queue, the delay with video seems to happen when the memory overflows.

1. What can i do to avoid memory overflow and delay with video with causes desync with video and audio?

After the pipeline is terminated it takes along time for it get saved.

2. I need the video to be saved instantly or fast as possible, what can i do to achieve this?

When running the pipeline without saving the video the memory does not seem to overflow.

Any tips are suggestion is much appreciated.